# Visit new url Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing, lit-element

I'm new to Cypress. My app as a "routing system" manually changes `window.location.hash`.
At some point, I click on a button that changes the hash and consequently should change the page during the test. I can see a "new url" entry appearing during the execution, but how can I make cypress visit that url?

[image]

**In few words, what the problem is:** you can see I type the password and then `{enter}`. Running the test I can see the hash change in the address bar, but the page doesn't change in accord to the hash change.

This is the testing code

```
context("Workflow", () => {

    it("login", () => {

        cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/src/#login")
        cy.get("#username").type("demo").should("have.value", "demouser")
        cy.get("#password").type("demo{enter}").should("have.value", "demo") // this should redirect to "/#home"
        //cy.wait(10000)
        cy.get(".subtitle").should("have.value", "Welcome") //this line fails as ".subtitle" is an element of "/#home"
    })
})
```

**EDIT:** Following tons of failed attempts, I came up with a partially working, clunky and hacky solution. I think I shouldn't need to use `reload()` to solve that (there must be a better solution..), but to make it works I have to wait for all the remote requests to be done (otherwise `reload()` cancels them). I say partially working because you can see from the comments in the code if I try to visit `#login` first, then follow the redirect in `#home` and then change the page to `#browser`, the last one doesn't work (I can see the hash changing to `#browser`, but the page is still `#home`).

```
import 'cypress-wait-until';

let i = 0;

context("Workflow", () => {
    it("login", () => {
        cy.server( {
            onRequest: () => {
                i++;
            },
            onResponse: () => {
                i--;
            }
        });

        cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/src/#login")
        cy.get("#username").type("demouser").should("have.value", "demouser")
        cy.get("#password").type("demouser").should("have.value", "demouser")
        cy.get("form#formLogin").submit()

        cy.waitUntil(() => i > 0)
        cy.waitUntil(() => i === 0)
        cy.reload(); // it correctly change the hash AND the page to #home!

        cy.url().should("include", "#home") 
        cy.get(".version").contains( "v2.0.0-beta") // it works!!

        cy.get("a[data-id=browser]").click({force: true}) // it correctly changes the hash to #browser
        cy.waitUntil(() => i > 0)
        cy.waitUntil(() => i === 0)
        cy.reload();

        // the hash in the address bar is #browser, but the web page is #home
    })
})
```

Comment: Have you tried `cy.visit()`?

Comment: `cy.visit()` takes the url as argument. I don't need that. I simply need to visit the page the menu button is pointing to.

Comment: So you're clicking a button, and it manually changes the anchor AKA the `window.location.hash`. When you manually click on the button in the webpage, are you redirected to the anchor?

Comment: of course it works, the website itself works fine. The whole problem is when I run it in cypress, I click a button using  `cy.find("#mybutton").click() ` and cypress simply doesn't change the page.

Comment: What's going on with the blurred out XHR requests in the image? Are any of them returning status code 302 or 303?

Comment: Also, can you add a `cy.wait(10000)` after the button is clicked to see if it ever redirects?

Comment: All the XHR requests returns a status `200`. I tried to `cy.wait(10000)` not solved. It is not matter of waiting, cypress simply doesn't follow that link.

Comment: You never specified what is the issue? Your page is not loading or there is some other code afterwards which is failing?

Comment: Just that page is not loading. So the test fails if I do `cy.find()` on an element on that page. But it doesn't fails simply clicking on the menu button which is suppose to change the page.

Comment: You said that you clicked a button, but that is not shown on the log above. Probably because `cy.find("#mybutton")` is invalid syntax, see [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find.html#Usage). It would be much more helpful to show the test code.

Comment: edited with the real code. The selectors `#username` and `#password` aren't a problem, I see cypress fills these input fields.

Comment: I start to think the issue is somehow related to `LitElement` itself (which I use in the web-app).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the attempts to solve, but they were all tricky workarounds to something as simple as "trigger the related listener when `window.location.hash` changes".

The root of the problem was a **bug in Cypress**. The bug on `window.location.hash` is present in `4.5.0`, but it has been solved somewhere between `4.5.0` and `4.12.1`.

**In `4.12.1` the problem is solved.**

Answer (score 8):

Cypress has an event called `url:changed`. See doc on **Events** [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Event-Types)

Using this, something like this *may* work:

```
context("Workflow", () => {
    it("login", () => {

        cy.on('url:changed', url => {
            cy.location('hash').then(hash => {
                if (!url.endsWith(hash)) {
                    cy.visit(url);
                }
            });
        });

        cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/src/#login")
        cy.get("#username").type("demo").should("have.value", "demouser")
        cy.get("#password").type("demo{enter}").should("have.value", "demo") // this should redirect to "/#home"
        cy.get(".subtitle").should("have.value", "Welcome") //this line fails as ".subtitle" is an element of "/#home"

    })
})
```

Edit: just for troubleshooting purposes and to focus on your issue, can you try it like this without `cy.location()`:

```
context("Workflow", () => {
    it("login", () => {

        cy.on('url:changed', url => {
            cy.visit(url);
        });

        cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/src/#login")
        cy.get("#username").type("demo").should("have.value", "demouser")
        cy.get("#password").type("demo{enter}").should("have.value", "demo") // this should redirect to "/#home"
        cy.get(".subtitle").should("have.value", "Welcome") //this line fails as ".subtitle" is an element of "/#home"

    })
})
```

Edit: Have you tried [`cy.reload()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/reload.html#Syntax)

```
context("Workflow", () => {

    it("login", () => {

        cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/src/#login")
        cy.get("#username").type("demo").should("have.value", "demouser")
        cy.get("#password").type("demo{enter}").should("have.value", "demo") // this should redirect to "/#home"
        cy.reload();
        cy.get(".subtitle").should("have.value", "Welcome");
    })
})
```

Comment: your code throws an error:  `Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.
The command that returned the promise was:
  > cy.visit()
The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:
  > cy.location()`

Comment: Did you have time to try without `cy.location()`

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer, SO doesn't send notification in case of post edit. I tried and I get the pretty much the same error `The command that returned the promise was:

  > cy.visit()

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

  > cy.visit()`

Comment: One more thing to try :)

Comment: With that I got another error. It seems the REST login request is cancelled if I use `cy.reload()` See screenshot https://postimg.cc/4K57Z4jW

Comment: Do you have a button that you can click to submit your credentials instead of using `{enter}` from your password form. You might get a different outcome.

Comment: There is also a `submit()` command that you can use on a `form` element like: `cy.get('form').submit()`

Comment: I had already tried to explicitly click on submit, exactly same outcome.

Comment: Anyway I noticed a strange behaviour. If I manually click on a button that is supposed to change the hash (and consequently change the page) from WITHIN the cypress browser, it does not actually change anything but the hash in the address bar. Of course, if I run my application outside cypress it works.

Comment: Did you try running your cypress test in Chrome instead of Electron?

Comment: Last comment and I give up after :) . I found this when searching for cypress with litElements and shadow DOM. https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-shadow-dom

Comment: nop, I deactivated shadow-dom overriding `createRenderRoot` in ALL my webcomponents. Please see my edited question, with a partially working (yet basically useless) solution.

Comment: I think I got the root of the problems: if I add `alert(1)` in the method `firstUpdated()` in the main LitElement component (to put in simple words that means as soon as the DOM is ready) I cannot see the alert! It's like javascript is "partially" disabled! What could be the reason of that?

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to do that. One of the basic approach is like this:

```
  cy.visit(`your_login_page`)
  cy.get('[data-testid="input-username"]').type(`demo`, { force: true })
  cy.get('[data-testid="input-password"]')
    .type(`demo`, {
      force: true,
    })
    .wait(1000)
    .then(() => {
      cy.location().should((loc) => {
        expect(loc.pathname).to.eq(your_new_url)
      })
    })
```

You should add `data-testid` or `findByTestId` to your elements with a unique id.
To visit the new URL, you can use `cy.visit(loc.pathname)`

Comment: Thanks, In my case would be `expect(loc.hash).to.eq("#home")` as if you change just the `hash` the `pathname` is the same. Anyway again, that kind of assertion doesnt' fails, but cypress actually doesn't change the page in accord to the hash change. So it will fail if I try to search an element on the home page like `cy.get(".subtitle")`